# Object manipulation in javascript in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var userLists = {
    user0 : {username: 'user9110252username', genrePref: 'user9110252genre'},
    user1 : {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
    user2 : {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
    user3 : {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
}
```

I am getting input like userLists.user from somewhere it should be like userLists.user0 how can i convert this request

```
var i =0;
for(var key in userLists) {
   console.log(userLists.user+i)
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Just use `console.log(userLists[key])`. You don't need another `i` variable. Also, consider using a users array instead of using consecutive numeral keys

Comment: Is it possible to use foreach for iteration of javascript ??

Comment: Please add the code

Comment: var i = 0;
userLists.forEach((key, value) => {
  console.log(key);
        i++
}) is this possible in object iteration ?

Comment: @SunilDubey `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userLists)) { console.log(key); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `forEach` or `map` you can do that on arrays but since you have an object you can use `Object.entries` for getting an array of arrays. There are also `Object.keys` and `Object.values`.

```js
var userLists = {
    user0 : {username: 'user9110252username', genrePref: 'user9110252genre'},
    user1 : {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
    user2 : {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
    user3 : {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
}

Object.entries(userLists).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value);
})
```

Comment: hmm but Is there any way to fix this code ?

var i =0;
for(var key in userLists) {
   console.log(userLists.user+i)
   i++;
}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, do you want like this ?

```js
var userLists = {
    user0 : {username: 'user9110252username', genrePref: 'user9110252genre'},
    user1 : {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
    user2 : {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
    user3 : {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
}

var result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(userLists).map(([k,v], i)=>[k=i, v]));

console.log(result);
```

Or you can do similar manipulation inside `map function` according to your requirement.